# jquery ui - show selected option on multiselect widget

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a Jquery UI multiselect box.

If I access the box like this

```
category = $("#edit_category").val();
```

I see that it has a value already in there. I want this value to be visible from the beginning. I read somewhere that it'd be useful to set the "option tag" of the multiselect from "selected" to "selected"... I'm not sure what this means.

thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah this helped me!

http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/6-jquery-snippets-you-can-use-to-manipulate-select-inputs/#comment-652

## 2  $('#selectList :selected').text();

Answer (score 1):

`I read somewhere that it'd be useful to set the "option tag" of the multiselect from "selected" to "selected"... I'm not sure what this means.`

it means that it would be the default selected option when the page loads